# Suppose that $F$ is an $m$-dimensional vector space over a subfield $K$ of $F$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

In Roman, Advanced Linear Algebra, there is a question: 
"Suppose that $F$ is an $m$-dimensional vector space over a subfield $K$ of $F$. If $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over $F$, show that $V$ is also a vector space over $K$. What is the dimension of $V$ as a vector space over $K$?". Any help with this problem would be appreciated. I cannot really make sense of $F$ being an $m$-dimensional vector space and also a field.

Comment: An example: $\mathbf C$ is a $2$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbf R$, and a basis is the set $\{1;,i\}$.

Comment: Thanks Bernard! I think I get it now. Then the dimension of $V$ as a vector space over $K$ is $n$ times $m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to understand the problem is to consider an example.  In particular, note that the complex numbers $F = \Bbb C$ contain the real numbers $K = \Bbb R$ as a subfield.

$F$ is a vector space in the following sense: if we have any two numbers $z_1,z_2 \in F$ and any scalars $c_1,c_2 \in K$, then $c_1z_1 + c_2 z_2$ is another element of $K$.  Moreover, because the definition of scalar multiplication is a "natural" consequence of multiplication in $F$, we can see that $F$ will satisfy the vector-space axioms.  I suggest that you convince yourself that $\Bbb C$ is a vector space over $\Bbb R$ and then argue the more general statement along similar lines.

So what is the dimension of $\Bbb C$ over $\Bbb R$? Because every complex number can be uniquely written as $a + bi$, the set $\{1,i\} \subset \Bbb C$ forms a *basis* of $\Bbb C$ as an $\Bbb R$-vector space.  So, $\Bbb C$ is a $2$-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb R$.

Now, $V = \Bbb C^n$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb C$.  What is its dimension over $\Bbb R$? In other words, how many real numbers are needed to uniquely specify an element of $\Bbb C^n$?  Use your conclusion here to get a more general answer.

Comment: Thanks! I would say it is $2n$.

Comment: @Emma That's right; though I guess Bernard's comment beat me to the punch here.  Anyway, other examples of fields and subfields are less intuitive if you haven't seen them before, but you can get very far by first answering this question for a specific example, then making the argument as general as possible.